# Alterar cor de background e ligar todas as luzes das janelas quando for noite (apenas JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, dom

Estou estudando JavaScript e resolvi criar um projeto prático, o qual consiste em um prédio que posso ligar e desligar as luzes clicando nas janelas, até ai ok.

Porém queria implementar a função de clicar em algum botão e mudar de dia para noite e todas as luzes se ligarem automaticamente.

A parte de mudar de dia para noite consegui, clicando na própria tela, porém quando clico para ligar ou apagar alguma luz fica mudando de dia para noite também.

Tentei algumas funções e meio diferentes, mas fico travado nisso. Alguém poderia dar um help por favor?

**HTML**

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('.ligaDesliga').forEach(divs => {
      divs.addEventListener('click', event => {
        divs.classList.toggle('yellow');
      })
    })
    
    let ambiente = document.querySelector('.day');
    
    function alterarHorario(){
      ambiente.addEventListener('click', alterar =>{
        ambiente.classList.toggle('night')
      })
    }
    
    alterarHorario();
```

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .day{
        background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .night{
        background-color: black;
    }
    
    .container{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 110vh;
    }
    
    .container .predio{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: space-between;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 560px;
        width: 250px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    
    #window1, #window2, #window3, #window4, #window5, #window6, #window7, #window8, #window9, #window10, #window11, #window12{
        width: 85px;
        height: 60px;
        background: black;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #window2, #window4, #window6, #window8, #window10, #window12{
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .door{
        width: 40px;
        height: 80px;
        background-color: brown;
        position: relative;
        bottom: -18px;
    }
    
    .yellow{
        background-color: yellow !important;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow,
                    0 0 15px yellow,
                    0 0 20px yellow; 
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Desafio prédio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="day">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="predio">
                        <div id="window1" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window2" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window3" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window4" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window5" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window6" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window7" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window8" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window9" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window10" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window11" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div id="window12" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
                        <div class="door"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: você está associando um evento dentro de uma function, isso deveria ser feito fora dela, como o outro evento com a classe "ligaDesliga"

Comment: @RicardoPontual apliquei da mesma forma que o outro evento, porém quando está no modo night e clico em alguma luz para ligar fica alterando a cor de fundo também de dia e noite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `ambiente.setAttribute('class', '...');` para alterar a cor de fundo. Você pode selecionar todos os elementos que possuem a classe `yellow`, e verificar se existe alguma elemento com essa classe fazendo um `.length`. Depois com um simples `if`, você decide se adicionaremos a classe `day` ou `night` dependendo se algum elemento ainda possui a classe `yellow`.

Veja o `if` dentro da função `alterarHorario`:

```
function alterarHorario() {
  ambiente.addEventListener('click', (alterar) => {
    const hasYellow = document.getElementsByClassName('yellow'); // retorna um array

    if (hasYellow.length) { // se houver alguem com a classe yellow
      ambiente.setAttribute('class', 'night'); // o tema de fundo será "night"
    } else {
      ambiente.setAttribute('class', 'day'); // se não houver ninguém com a classe 
                                             // "yellow", o tema será "day"
    }
  });
}
```

O código funcionando:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ligaDesliga').forEach((divs) => {
  divs.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    divs.classList.toggle('yellow');
  });
});

let ambiente = document.querySelector('.day');

function alterarHorario() {
  ambiente.addEventListener('click', (alterar) => {
    const hasYellow = document.getElementsByClassName('yellow'); 

    if (hasYellow.length) {
      ambiente.setAttribute('class', 'night');
    } else {
      ambiente.setAttribute('class', 'day');
    }
  });
}

alterarHorario();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.day {
  background-color: blue;
}

.night {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 110vh;
}

.container .predio {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 560px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
}

#window1,
#window2,
#window3,
#window4,
#window5,
#window6,
#window7,
#window8,
#window9,
#window10,
#window11,
#window12 {
  width: 85px;
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#window2,
#window4,
#window6,
#window8,
#window10,
#window12 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.door {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: brown;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -18px;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow, 0 0 15px yellow, 0 0 20px yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Projeto</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="day">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="predio">
          <div id="window1" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window2" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window3" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window4" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window5" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window6" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window7" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window8" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window9" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window10" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window11" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window12" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div class="door"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

É claro que o código acima pode ficar melhor, mas espero que tenha entendido a lógica.

Para ligar todas as "luzes" quando clicar em uma janela, basta adicionar o código:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ligaDesliga').forEach((el) => {
  el.classList.toggle('yellow');
});
```

dentro de:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ligaDesliga').forEach((divs) => {
  divs.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.ligaDesliga').forEach((el) => {
      el.classList.toggle('yellow');
    });
  });
});
```

Que irá adicionar a classe `yellow` para todas as janelas, quando qualquer uma delas for clicada.

Código completo:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ligaDesliga').forEach((divs) => {
  divs.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.ligaDesliga').forEach((el) => {
      el.classList.toggle('yellow');
    });
  });
});

let ambiente = document.querySelector('.day');

function alterarHorario() {
  ambiente.addEventListener('click', (alterar) => {
    const hasYellow = document.getElementsByClassName('yellow'); 

    if (hasYellow.length) {
      ambiente.setAttribute('class', 'night');
    } else {
      ambiente.setAttribute('class', 'day');
    }
  });
}

alterarHorario();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.day {
  background-color: blue;
}

.night {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 110vh;
}

.container .predio {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 560px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
}

#window1,
#window2,
#window3,
#window4,
#window5,
#window6,
#window7,
#window8,
#window9,
#window10,
#window11,
#window12 {
  width: 85px;
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#window2,
#window4,
#window6,
#window8,
#window10,
#window12 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.door {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: brown;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -18px;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow, 0 0 15px yellow, 0 0 20px yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Projeto</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="day">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="predio">
          <div id="window1" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window2" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window3" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window4" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window5" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window6" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window7" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window8" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window9" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window10" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window11" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div id="window12" class="ligaDesliga"></div>
          <div class="door"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Opa legal, agora entendi um pouco melhor a lógica ali, vou ir tentando adaptar até ficar como estou imaginando, mas você já me deu uma boa ideia, lhe agradeço